# Getting security properties of an AD object in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to code up a simple C# method to grab a list of objects in AD (that's the easy part I can do in my sleep) and list all the various security properties of each object to see who has read, write, create child objects, delete file objects, etc permissions on each AD object.

The purpose of this is to to do a quick audit of security permissions, and this will be part of a larger C# program that does a bunch of other audits at the same time.

Any help or ideas on getting this done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: literally not much. I am (for now) working on security group permissions, so I have the following:

            DirectoryEntry de= new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=directory,DC=local");
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectCategory=group)");
            search.PageSize = 500;
            SearchResultCollection src = search.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
// not sure what to do with each search result at this point

Comment: @Kevin. did you find any solution for your issue?